# How to reference child view in adapter class from fragment

Tags: java, android

I have childblog.xml

```
<TextView                            
    android:id="@+id/tv_fab1"
    adroid:layout_width="wrap_content"                            
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:text="Google+"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="16dp"
     />
```

I have the adapter class which inflate the above childblog layout for each item in the recycleview.

```
@Override
public Holder_blog onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.child_blog, parent, false);
    Holder_blog holder_blog = new Holder_blog(view);
    return holder_blog;
}
```

And I am trying to refer the textview of childblog in my fragment which hold the recycleview

```
  @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blog, container, false);
    System.out.println("Current Class===>>>" + getClass().getSimpleName());
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).enable_imv_drawer_mainactivity();

    tv_fab1 = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.tv_fab1);
```

I have getting  a null object reference. How can I get hold of the textview of the childblog in the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
tv_fab1 = (TextView) container.findViewById(R.id.tv_fab1);
```

to

```
tv_fab1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_fab1);
```